# Call a generic method and set the generic type at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

In the example bellow, is it possible to set the Classname type parameter dynamically?

```
UpdateAndSave<Classname>>().Execute(sql)
```

Comment: There's a very cute trick for this if the method takes an instance as a parameter; if this was `UpdateAndSave<T>(T theObject)`, it would be pretty trivial - *even if you don't know the object type* (i.e. the caller just knows `object theObject`).

Comment: Sadly you have to write messy reflection code to achieve this as the language cannot natively support it.

Comment: @DavidArno the language *comes very close* though (see answer)

Comment: @MarcGravell You sir are evil! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your type is coming from an object, then you can cheat using `dynamic` - hijacking it to perform (and cache, via meta-programming etc) the type resolution for you. For example - if you currently have:

```
object obj = ...
Type type = obj.GetType();
// now want to call UpdateAndSave<type>(...)
```

then you can do:

```
public void Voodoo<T>(T obj, string sql) {
    UpdateAndSave<T>().Execute(sql);
}
```

and just:

```
object obj = ...
Voodoo((dynamic)obj, sql);
```

The runtime will detect the type of `obj`, determine the best overload to use (which will be `Voodoo<TheActualType>(...)`), and *call that*. Plus it will cache the strategy for that type, so it is fast next time (it only does any significant work once per unique type).

Answer (score 4):

Well you can call it by reflection, yes - using [`MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) to provide the type arguments:

```
var method = typeof(Whatever).GetMethod("UpdateAndSave");
var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeArgument);
genericMethod.Invoke(target, new object[] { sql });
```

Comment: Do you prefer this over [Marc's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19835099/18192)?

Comment: @Brian: That's assuming you've got an object - if you've *just* got a type, it won't work. But both are viable.